# How to convert 3 arrays into a single Object in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I am working on an Angular project and I am fetching data from [this API](https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries)

Then I do this:

```js
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  readonly API_URL = 'https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries';

  country = [];
  cases = [];
  deaths = [];
  recovered = [];

  countriesData: Object;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.httpClient.get(this.API_URL).subscribe((data: Array<any>) => {
      data = data.filter(c => c.country !== 'World');

      data.forEach(y => {
        englishToGreek(this.country, y.country);
        this.cases.push(y.cases);
        this.deaths.push(y.deaths);
        this.recovered.push(y.recovered);
      });
      console.table(this.countriesData);
    });
  }
}
```

The `englishToGreek()` function translates country names from English to Greek, the source code is this:

```js
const lexor = new Map();

lexor.set('World', 'Παγκοσμίος'); // in extreme cases
lexor.set('USA', 'Η.Π.Α / Αμερική');
lexor.set('Spain', 'Ισπανία');
lexor.set('Italy', 'Ιταλία');
lexor.set('France', 'Γαλλία');
lexor.set('Iran', 'Ιράν');
lexor.set('Germany', 'Γερμανία');
lexor.set('UK', 'Ηνωμένο Βασίλειο');
lexor.set('Turkey', 'Τουρκία');
lexor.set('Switzerland', 'Ελβετία');
lexor.set('Netherlands', 'Ολλανδία');
lexor.set('Canada', 'Καναδάς');
lexor.set('Belgium', 'Βέλγιο');

function englishToGreek(pushableObject, countryName) {
  pushableObject.push(lexor.get(countryName));
}
```

How can I combine the 3 arrays `this.cases, this.deaths, this.recovered` and assign the result to the `this.countriesData` object?

Comment: Can you create the interface for "countriesData" to give more information about what you want?

Comment: @Lievno what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import the lexor map into same component and use the following code to accomplish your task.

```
 data.forEach(y => {
    this.country.push({
      country: lexor.get(y.country),
      cases: y.cases,
      deaths: y.deaths,
      recovered: y.recovered,
    })
  });
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying but I want the data to be stored inside the countriesData Object. How can I do that? Thank you

Comment: In question you have written i want to combine this.deaths, this.cases and this.recovered. What do you mean by combine ?? How do you want to combine, how it should look like after combination ?

Comment: Nevermind! I just made an another array and then I pushed everything in it.